# QFormLayout Positioning

Tags: python, pyqt5, qformlayout

I am using formlayout but it placed all buttons at top-right corner. Is there anyway to change the  position of buttons while they are in QFormlayout. I mean move the black box from top left corner to bottom right corner where arrow locates.

[image]

```
def layout(self):

    form_layout = QFormLayout()
    form_layout.addRow('Lat_Min: ',self.Lat_min)
    form_layout.addRow('Lat_Max: ',self.Lat_max)
    form_layout.addRow('Lon_Min: ',self.Lon_min)
    form_layout.addRow('Lon_Max: ',self.Lon_max)
    form_layout.addRow(self.b1)
    form_layout.addRow(self.run)
    form_layout.addRow(self.target)
    form_layout.addRow(self.b2)


    h_layout = QHBoxLayout()
    h_layout.addLayout(form_layout)
    h_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
```

Comment: please provide a [mre] also your question is confusing, you could show an image of what you want to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you are trying to move all of the buttons from the left side of the image to the right from your description...

Try swapping the order of the last two lines of code to:

```
h_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
h_layout.addLayout(form_layout)
```

Edit: To answer the question about moving the buttons from the rights side of the page to the bottom of the page.

So you are using the `QHBoxLayout`, H standing for horizontal, when you need to be using the `QVBoxLayout`. Documentation is found [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvboxlayout.html). Your last lines of code should then be as follows:

```
    v_layout = QVBoxLayout()
    v_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
    v_layout.addLayout(form_layout)
```

Comment: i am actually want to move them at the bottom of my window...can u advise?

Comment: Can you provide a sketch of what you want? What is "them"? Is it the entire form_layout or just the buttons?

Comment: form_layout.addRow('Lat_Min: ',self.Lat_min)
    form_layout.addRow('Lat_Max: ',self.Lat_max)
    form_layout.addRow('Lon_Min: ',self.Lon_min)
    form_layout.addRow('Lon_Max: ',self.Lon_max)
    form_layout.addRow(self.b1)
    form_layout.addRow(self.run)
    form_layout.addRow(self.target)
    form_layout.addRow(self.b2)


I want move all those buttons from topright of my window to bottom-right corner